# How to give ranks to multiple columns data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have input table as shown below -

```
ID  Name q1     q2      q3      q4
1   a    2621   2036    1890    2300
2   b    18000  13000   14000   15000
3   c    100    200     300     400
```

I want ranking of columns(`q1, q2, q3 and q4`) data for each row. For example, if I consider last row of above input, then `q4` column contains `400` value which is higher than other columns, so rank to `q4` column will be `1`, `q3` rank will be `2`, `q2` rank will be `3` and `q1` rank will be `4`.

I am looking for output like -

```
id  name  q1  q2  q3  q4
1   a     1   3   4   2
2   b     1   4   3   2
3   c     4   3   2   1
```

There are more than 100,000 records present in input table.

I have created small SQL script for input table i.e.,

```
declare @temp table (ID int, Name varchar(10), q1 int, q2 int, q3 int, q4 int)

insert into @temp
select 1, 'a', 2621, 2036, 1890, 2300
union all
select 2, 'b', 18000, 13000, 14000, 15000
union all
select 3, 'c', 100, 200, 300, 400

select * from @temp
```

Please help me to find efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Have you tried ranking with ... [the ranking functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ??

Comment: Looks like you want to rank row-wise, rather than column-wise. You'd probably need to pivot, rank, and unpivot.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to get the rank of different columns in a row, not within a set column; aggregate functions work at column level, not row (another reason why you should keep your data normalised). You'll going to need to pivot your data, to normalise it, and then unpivot it back.

Comment: Beat me to it @HoneyBadger :)

Comment: @Larnu, makes a change, usually you're first with an answer I had in my mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `UNPIVOT` & `PIVOT` :

```
SELECT Id, Name, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN qname = 'q1' THEN SEQ END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN qname = 'q2' THEN SEQ END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN qname = 'q3 'THEN SEQ END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN qname = 'q4 'THEN SEQ END)
FROM (SELECT t.*, tt.*, 
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Name ORDER BY tt.qq DESC) AS SEQ
      FROM @temp t CROSS APPLY
           ( VALUES (q1, 'q1'), (q2, 'q2'), (q3, 'q3'), (q4, 'q4') 
           ) tt(qq, qname)
     ) t
GROUP BY t.Id, t.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks @Yogesh. You crack it really quick.